# UIActionsheet on rotation

Tags: ios, uiactionsheet

I am launching an **UIActionsheet** in my app.On rotation, the action sheet is not centrally aligned ,so On rotation I dismiss the actionsheet and reOpen it using

```
[actionsheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:NO];
[actionsheet showInView:self.view];
```

But the problem is in **iOS6** it throws the following error

* Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time! View > is associated with <_UIActionSheetHostingController: 0x18615830>. Clear this association before associating this view with <_UIActionSheetHostingController: 0xe0f28b0>.'

I tried using:

```
[actionsheet showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.view];
```

but still I get the same error.

Everything works fine on **iOS7**.

I have searched a lot but fixes are mostly done through XIBs.I want to solve it programmatically. Does anyone has any idea about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT** : Reason for this issue is removing and showing cannot be done at a same time

```
[actionsheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:NO];
//adding some delay as dismissing one actionsheet and presenting actionsheet after some time
[self performSelector:@selector(showActionSheet) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
```

Add these below method :

```
-(void)showActionSheet
{
  [actionsheet showInView:self.view];
}
```

Comment: This issue occure again if the keyboard is open in the same view with the action sheet. Do you know how to solve this problem?